# How Do I Clear JSON cache in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, caching

I have a method which pulls a string from my database (I'm using nodejs and mongodb). When my app makes the call data is returned. But my app won't make the same call again. For example when I type in a username: JohnDoe123, I expect the backend to send back an ID associated with JohnDoe123, which it does. But I want to be able to make that same query again, so do I need to clear the cache somehow?

```
 if ([jsonn objectForKey:@"success"]) {
    NSNumber* successful = [jsonn objectForKey:@"success"];
    if ([successful boolValue]) {
        NSString* idforpic = (NSString*)[jsonn objectForKey:@"idforpic"];
        NSLog(@"idforpic: %@", idforpic);
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:idforpic forKey:@"CURRENTPICID"];
        if (idforpic != nil) {
        picView = [[ProfilePicViewController alloc] initWithId:idforpic];
        [picView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 3, self.view.frame.size.width, 150)];
        [picView setImageUsingId:idforpic];
        [self addChildViewController:picView];
        [self.view addSubview:picView.view];
            removePicView = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeProfilePicViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, I need to be able to run everything included in if(idforpic != nil) multiple times

Comment: There is no "JSON cache".  Your device and any router between there and the server may have a cache, though, such that any *identical* request sent may produce the "old" value rather than a new one.

Comment: is there any way to produce a new value?

Comment: There is a way to tell the device to clear it's cache.  There is also a flag you can put in your request to tell routers to not cache the response (though how well the flag is honored is hard to guess).  The only reasonably reliable approach is to never issue the same (identical) request twice.

Comment: Presumably if your request is for JohnDoe123 that value is in the request somewhere.